# Error with given arguments and numpy - Python

Tags: python, numpy, arguments

I have the following father class and method:

```
import SubImage
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
import random

class Image():

    # Class constructor
    def __init__(self):
        self.__image = np.empty(0)
        self.__rows = 0
        self.__cols = 0
        self.__rows_pixels = 0
        self.__cols_pixels = 0
        self.__rows_quotient = 0.0
        self.__cols_quotient = 0.0
        self.__create_image()
        self.__subimages = np.empty((self.__rows, self.__cols))

    def __create_subimages(self):
        i = 0
        j = 0

        while i != self.__rows_quotient * self.__rows:
            print (i+j)
            sub_image = SubImage(self.__image[i:i + self.__rows_quotient, j:j + self.__cols_quotient], i + j)
            if j == self.__cols_quotient * (self.__cols - 1):
                j = 0
                i += self.__rows_quotient
            else:
                j += self.__cols_quotient
```

And the following subclass which is supposed to be a child from the class above:

```
import Image

class SubImage(Image):

    def __init__(self, image, position):
        self.__position = position
        self.__image = image
```

My problem is that when creating a SubImage instance in the __create_subimages method I get the following error:

```
File "/home/mitolete/PycharmProjects/myprojectSubImage.py", line 3, in <module>
    class SubImage(Image):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I don't get why it says I'm giving 3 arguments, I'm giving 2 which is the subimage (a numpy array) and an integer.

WHy is this?

Regards and thanks.

Comment: Is the indentation incorrect here or is it indented as in the file you're running? The method should be indented to the same level as class.

Comment: The identation is right, it's just in the code here, I'll edit it.

Comment: Ah, actually, I might see what's going on. What is your directory structure like? It looks like you have a SubImage module, meaning the import might actually have to look like `from SubImage import SubImage`.

Comment: I get: ImportError: cannot import name Image with that :/

Answer (score 0):

If you're importing `SubImage` from another file, i.e. a module, you will have to reference that in the import. In this case, assuming `SubImage` is in a file called `SubImage.py`, the import should be

```
from SubImage import SubImage
```

so that `SubImage` now refers to the class `SubImage` in `SubImage.py`. This is also the case for `Image` in `Image.py`.

However, I don't think there's a need to do this given how closely related the two classes are. I'd put them in the same file and avoid the circular import.

Comment: I get: ImportError: cannot import name Image with that :/

Comment: What does the directory look like? Is it just `Image.py` and `SubImage.py`?

Comment: [link]/Persitence/Image.py[/link] and [link]/Persistence/SubImage.py[/link]  I removed the Import Image from the Image.py and I didn't get that error, but now I get that I can't create a [link]SubImage[/link] instance because [link}Subimag{/link}e isn't defined

Comment: The circular imports here will cause you some pain. I have to go to a meeting now but when I get back I'll edit my answer with some ideas for how to handle the inheritance here.

Comment: The main use is that I want to create a child class in the parent class...

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to keep them in the same file? That'll fix your import issue. Given that they're so tied together, it seems a reasonable separation of concerns.

Comment: Yeah, we must have every class in a different file said by the professor.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is the way you import both Image and Subimage into each other.

Subimage should be imported this way:

```
from myprojectSubImage import SubImage
```

Image should be imported this way:

```
from FILENAME import Image
```

that being said, the mutual import seems like bad practice. you should probably either merge the Image and SubImage file, or move the 'create_subimages' function to another file.

Comment: how does it make sense to import each class to itself?

Comment: you don't import each class to itself. you import the first line to the image file, and the second line to the subimage file.

Comment: yesh i got confused bec you said it the other way arround, ill try that thanks